# Cocoa Webview - HTML5 fullscreen not working within WebView(WKWebView) on OSX

Tags: html, cocoa, video, webview, fullscreen

I'm trying to build an osx application with an integrated webkit webview to display a web page. On the webpage are html5 video elements which the user should be able to play in fullscreen. But fullscreen not working on mountain lion (10.11.4) when I clicked the "Full-screen" button(Everything are working fine with Safari or Chrome), is this a bug or did I miss something.

HTTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Full-screen JavaScript Controller</title>
    <style>
        #video-player:-webkit-full-screen {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-color: black;
        }
        #video-player:-webkit-full-screen video {
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function playPause() {
            var myVideo = document.querySelector('video');
            if (myVideo.paused)
                myVideo.play();
            else
                myVideo.pause();
         }
        function goFullscreen() {
            var myPlayer = document.getElementById('video-player');
            myPlayer.webkitRequestFullscreen();
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="video-player">
        <video src="http://www.quirksmode.org/html5/videos/big_buck_bunny.mp4"></video>
        <p><a href="javascript:playPause();">Play/Pause</a></p>
        <a href="javascript:goFullscreen();">Full-screen</a>
    </div>
</body>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSView* contentView = self.window.contentView;
    WebView* webview = [[WebView alloc]initWithFrame:contentView.bounds];
    NSURL* htmlPath = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"fullscreenTest_path/fullscreenTest.html"];
    NSString* data = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:[htmlPath path] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [[webview mainFrame]loadHTMLString:data baseURL:nil];
    [contentView addSubview:webview];
}
```

Comment: Would you try WKWebView instead of WebView?

Comment: Yes, I have tried it, the result is the same.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have a similar problem where I am opening youtube for testing but it always says full screen is unsupported.

Comment: There's no offcial API to support it.

Comment: See my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44988219/wkwebview-mac-browser-enable-fullscreen-html5/56998745#56998745 (note: You'll have to access private APIs)

Comment: Yes, the only way is to use the private API "_setFullScreenEnabled:".

Comment: There is another way without requiring private APIs, see the answer to this other question https://stackoverflow.com/a/65656250/4691224